# Exercise on the operator $g(t)\mapsto \sqrt \lambda g(\lambda t)$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, adjoint-operators

I have the linear operator $A_\lambda :g(t)\mapsto \sqrt \lambda g(\lambda t)$ on $C[0,1]$ with $\lambda\in (0,1)$ (which extends to $L^2[0,1]$). I need to find its adjoint and then prove that while $A_\lambda A_\lambda^\ast=1$, $A_\lambda ^\ast A_\lambda $ is  a projection. I also need to find what subspace it projects to.

After calculating I found $A_\lambda^\ast:g(t)\mapsto \frac1{\sqrt\lambda}g(\frac t\lambda)\cdot \chi_{[0,1]}(\frac t\lambda)$, since $$ \left\langle A_\lambda f,g \right\rangle =\sqrt \lambda\int _{[0,1]}f(\lambda t)g(t)dt=\frac1{\sqrt \lambda}\int _{[0,1]}f(t^\prime)g(\frac {t^\prime}\lambda)\chi_{[0,\lambda]}(t^\prime)dt^\prime$$ and $\chi_{[0,\lambda]}(t^\prime)=\chi_{[0,1]}(\frac {t^\prime}\lambda)$.

But then $A_\lambda A_\lambda^\ast=1=A_\lambda ^\ast A_\lambda $ and I don't see my mistake...

By the way, I calculated $\|A_\lambda\|=\lambda$. Is this correct?

Comment: Are you assuming $0\le \lambda \le 1$?

Comment: @πr8 sorry, forgot to mention - $\lambda\in (0,1)$

Comment: yes, because if $\lambda > 1$ it is the opposite : $A^* A = Id$ and $A A^*$ is a projection

Comment: @user1952009 I don't know what question "yes" answers - I'm getting both composites equal to the identity :(

Comment: Can you write the integral for $\langle Af,A g \rangle =\langle A^*A f,g \rangle$ ?

Comment: @user1952009 sure but I'd like to understand what my mistake is in composing these functions, because for $A^\ast _\lambda A_\lambda$ I'm getting $g(t)\mapsto \frac 1{\sqrt\lambda} (\sqrt \lambda g(\frac{\lambda t}\lambda))\cdot \chi_{[0,1]}(\frac{\lambda t}\lambda)=g(t)$

Comment: no this is not correct, but what you wrote for $\langle Af,g \rangle$ is, that's why I asked you to write $\langle Af,Ag \rangle$

Comment: @user1952009 $\langle Af,Ag \rangle= \lambda \int_{[0,1]}f(\lambda t)g(\lambda t)$. Anyway, I'm sure you're right and my composition is not correct, but could you pinpoint my mistake or how to properly compose these functions?

Comment: so that $\langle Af,A g \rangle = \int_0^\lambda f(x) g(x) dx$, i.e. the $[\lambda,1]$ part disappeared, hence no way that $A$ is inversible and that $A^*A = Id$  (and remember that $\langle Af,A g \rangle = \langle A^*Af, g \rangle$)

Comment: @user1952009 could you help me out in chat?

Comment: no there is no latex in chat

Comment: [There is](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/78279253/mathjax.html).

Comment: @user1952009 is my calculation of $A^\ast _\lambda$ wrong then? What should it be?

Comment: yes I know this but I didn't set it up :)

Comment: what you missed is that $\chi_{[0,1]}(t/\lambda) = \chi_{[0,\lambda]}(t)$ so $[A^*g](t)= ?$

Comment: @user1952009 but I didn't miss this - I wrote it explicitly and the post and used it :O

Comment: I don't know it is boring, find the mistake yourself :). Anyway $[A^* A f](t) = f(t) \chi_{[0,\lambda]}(t)$ is clearly a projection, you proved it with $\langle A^*Af,g\rangle = \langle Af,Ag\rangle= \int_0^\lambda  f(t) g(t) dt = \langle f \chi_{[0,\lambda]},g\rangle$

Comment: @user1952009 thanks but this is exactly my problem - just reading off the equation I wrote I find $A_\lambda^\ast:g(t)\mapsto \frac1{\sqrt\lambda}g(\frac t\lambda)\cdot \chi_{[0,1]}(\frac t\lambda)$ and for starters I'd like to know whether that's correct or not

Comment: @user1952009 I'm really having trouble. Could you tell me whether my adjoin is correct?

Comment: come on there is nothing complicated... $A$ stretches $f(t)$ so that some part falls outside of $[0,1]$, and this part is lost. $A^*$ un-stretch $f(t)$ but it cannot recover the lost part.  $A^*$ is loss-less, while $A$ isn't, overall $A^* A$ just cut the $[\lambda,1]$ part out, while $A A^*$ is the identity.

Comment: note that if $f(t)$ is zero on $[\lambda,1]$ then $A f$ is lossless and $A^* A f = f$, while if $f(t)$ is non-zero only on $[\lambda,1]$, then $Af = 0$ and $A^* A = 0$, i.e. $A^*A$ is an (orthogonal) projection : it is the identity on some subspace $E$, and $0$ on $E^\perp$